# How to change manager for custom User model

Tags: python, django

I've defined a custom user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    email = models.EmailField(
        _('email address'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Must be a valid email address.'),
        error_messages={
            'unique':_("A user with that email address already exists."),
        },
    )
```

The point of it being to use an email address instead of username.

I've put this in settings:

```
# custom user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'workoutcal.User'
```

The user model works, but there's one problem. I can't create superusers:

```
(workout) n155-p250:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ ./manage.py createsuperuser
Email address: sahandz@kth.se
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 179, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

Seems like the `create_superuser` method used has username as a required argument. I've read in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser) that I need to implement my own `CustomUserManager`. I've already done so here:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = User(email = email, is_staff=is_staff,
                    is_superuser=is_superuser, date_joined=now,
                    **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
```

It seems clear that my `CustomUserManager` *isn't managing* *the* `User` *model*. There seems to be no documentation telling me where to actually set the `CustomUserManager` as the *actual manager* for the `User` model. Could somebody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to tell the new user to use the new manager:

```
class User(AbstractUser): # in your custom user
    #...
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    #...
```

Django does the same thing [in the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ba4ffdc8771c2f38cf6de26a2b82bbceea2b933a/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L375)

As for:

> There seems to be no documentation telling me where to actually set the CustomUserManager as the actual manager for the User model.

Yes, there is actually a nice doc for that too, but explained in a more general way:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/